# I can't understand how this script functions

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, random

Card shuffling script

After both for loops have finished, have all the cards been labelled before function c has
been started?      **card1=2D    card2=2C   Card3=2H............... Card52=AS**

If that is how it works , how does it randomise them ?

The random number range is reduced by 1 after enter is pressed , if card52 hasn't been
been picked , how can it be picked if the range is now 51?

```
@echo off
title
rem %random%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set a=0
set e=52
set f=0
for %%a in (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A) do call :a "%%a"
goto c
:a arg1
set b= %~1
for %%b in (%~1D%b%C%b%H%b%S) do call :b "%%b"
exit /b 0
:b arg1
set /a a=a+1
set Card%a%=%~1
exit /b 0


:c
set /a c=%random%*%e%/32768+1
set d=!Card%c%!
set /a f=%f%+1
echo Card #%f%: %d%
echo.
pause
cls
set Card%c%=!Card%e%!
set /a e=%e%-1


if %e% neq 0 goto c
Pause
exit
```

Comment: Poorly. Randomisation is done using the `%random%` variable and It crudely shrinks the array in this line: 
    `set Card%c%=!Card%e%!`
This script fails to prevent multiple selections of the same card. Take a look [here](https://pastebin.com/76DhqD2V) for an example of using a list in combination with arrays to preclude multiple selections

Comment: I have checked the output a few times , there are no duplicates.

Comment: That is what confuses me.

Comment: You are correct about no duplicates, my mistake was in outputting the card array.  As it's overwitten in the line `set Card%c%=!Card%e%!` the array ends up with duplicates, not the actual output. Basically, after outputting the card, the array overwites the index output with the last index in the array before reducing the array size.

Comment: So after the for loops have completed , the cards are labelled card1=2D card2=2C......... Card52=AS ?  So when we are in function c , where the randomising takes place,  the script stays in function c ?

Comment: Yes, func's A + B define the card array. C is not a function as such, rather a label used for looping the action of dealing a card.  If you haven't already, consider reviewing the script I linked in my first comment for a slightly different but much clearer way of doing this.